# Get and add wordpress user name in between urls

Tags: php, html, wordpress

how to get current logged in wordpress user name and add that name in between a custom url like below

http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/members/**USER NAME HERE**/notifications/

Because i'm going to add this custom link in my theme menus
i can hard code for single user like this
http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/members/administrator/notifications/
but its wont work with other logged in user.

so how to get current logged in user name and add that name in between url???

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to wp_get_current_user() return WP_User object.

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

to be sure that u are logged in  :

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

You can use a hook and add the PHP programmatically in the function.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );
function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {

     if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        if( 'profil' == $item->post_title ) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $username = $current_user->user_login;
            $item->url .= '/members/' . $username./notifications;
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to add the username in between custom urls. i wan to add that url in wordpress custom link menu

Comment: can you explain more what you are looking to do ?

Comment: getting error "syntax error, unexpected '/'" in this line $item->url .= '/members/' . $username./notifications;

Comment: added parenthesis removed the error and it works $item->url .= ('http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/members/'. $username.'/notifications'); thanks a lot

Comment: Can you tell me what is the function of this line  if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

Comment: This Conditional Tag is_admin() checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed . if true you don't need to custom ur url . what you are looking for is to custom the URLs on the website not administration

Answer (score 0):

to get the current logged in user's username you can use wp_get_current_user();

for eg:-

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();

echo " http://192.168.1.10/wordpress/members/".$user->user_login."/notifications/";

?>
```

Comment: you have to use wp_get_current_user() to get current logged in user's info and then you can use the user_login to get username from the returned array

Comment: sorry to ask you again but i dont know php thats why using wordpress. i dont know  how to execute your instructions can you explain me in detail please

Comment: do you want to use this in a admin panel??

Comment: yeah.. in admin panel\appearance\menus